# Excel VBA - Error 91 problem when HTML value is nothing

Tags: html, excel, xml, vba, web-scraping

Hi I recently discovered excel VBA and am using it to aid my study of German.

I have a list of German words but no meaning/part of speech, example sentences, etc.

I wrote a macro to go to website (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/) and fetch html data.

However, for some words, the example sentences are not provided (Hence the html returning no value and the error 91).

I have referred to other posts concerning this and added If Not HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName() Is Nothing Then statements, but no luck so far.

Could you please tell me how to write a code such that if there is no html value, the macro moves on and go to the next word? (word is set by integer corresponding to the cell number in the excel sheet)

```
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strURL As String


    For i = 2 To 3493

        strURL = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/" & Range("A" & i)
        XMLReq.Open "Get", strURL, False
        XMLReq.send

        If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
            MsgBox "Error."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

        Set XMLReq = Nothing

        'Part
        If IsObject(HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("pos dpos")) Then
            Range("B" & i) = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("pos dpos")(0).innerText
        End If

        'Meaning
        If IsObject(HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("ddef_h")) Then
            Range("C" & i) = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("ddef_h")(0).innerText
        End If

        'ExampleGer

        If Not HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("eg deg") Is Nothing Then
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Range("D" & i) = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("eg deg")(0).innerText
        End If

        'ExampleEng
        If Not HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("trans dtrans hdb") Is Nothing Then
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Range("E" & i) = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("trans dtrans hdb")(0).innerText
        End If

    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Are your not's the wrong way round?  `if html.... is nothing then i=i+1 else....` should it be?

Comment: I have swapped the if no statements and else statements yet the same error persists... I don't know how to make the macro move on if there's no html value

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Range("C" & i) = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("ddef_h")(0).innerText

because the page for the word being searched has no ddef_h in the html

Comment: I would say `if not HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("ddef_h") is nothing`

Comment: I am sorry, could you please clarify? I am new to coding, when I write as you said it gives me "Compile error: Expected: Then or GoTo".

Comment: if not HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("ddef_h") is nothing then dosomething  end if  (remember to split if statement across separate lines)

Comment: Can you supply one example phrase that should work and one that fails?

Comment: Guys after struggling and trying out different methods I think I have found I a quick fix. by just adding ".Item" to `If Not HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("trans dtrans hdb").Item Is Nothing Then`
and then assigning the value to a cell worked for me. Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm a German and therefore did not need any example words.
A word that delivers all 4 values: Haus (house)
A word that delivers only 2 values: Gummibaum (rubber plant)

Try the following code and please ...

NEVER! NEVER! NEVER! manipulate the counting variable of a for loop in the code block of the loop. Never use this `i = i + 1` if `i` is the counting variable of the for loop. If you do that you run into problems in 99.9%

```
Sub Dictionary()

    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strURL As String

    'Use object variables for each node you want to read from the DOM tree
    'In the code below, these variables are then used to check whether an object exists or not
    Dim nodePart As Object
    Dim nodeMeaning As Object
    Dim nodeExampleGer As Object
    Dim nodeExampleEng As Object

    For i = 2 To 3493

        strURL = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/" & Range("A" & i)
        'strURL = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/haus"
        XMLReq.Open "Get", strURL, False
        XMLReq.send

        If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
            MsgBox "Error."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

        Set XMLReq = Nothing

        'Part
        Set nodePart = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("pos dpos")(0)
        If Not nodePart Is Nothing Then
            Range("B" & i) = nodePart.innerText
        End If

        'Meaning
        Set nodeMeaning = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("ddef_h")(0)
        If Not nodeMeaning Is Nothing Then
            Range("C" & i) = nodeMeaning.innerText
        End If

        'ExampleGer
        Set nodeExampleGer = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("eg deg")(0)
        If Not nodeExampleGer Is Nothing Then
            Range("D" & i) = nodeExampleGer.innerText
        End If

        'ExampleEng
        Set nodeExampleEng = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("trans dtrans hdb")(0)
        If Not nodeExampleEng Is Nothing Then
            Range("E" & i) = nodeExampleEng.innerText
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```